# How are the other games played in Ready or Not?

Tags: ready-or-not

In the 2019 film, Ready or Not, we learn about a specific game.

> Fitch mentions he had to play Old Maid on his wedding night.  Other games were mentioned around the table.
>  
>  We know that Grace's game was fraught with a killing ritual.  I would only assume there must be a twist to the other games, but I can't imagine what.  Maybe there is some lore out there, spread by the production crew?

How were the other games played by this family in similar ceremonies?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

## They were just regular games.

Hide and seek is the only game with a twist, where you have to try and kill someone. All others are harmless games. That's why the groom is so shocked at this, he didn't expect this particular game to happen. He expected just random games like chess or a card game (IIRC, some of these are mentioned to have been done by each other new member of the family).

In fact, this game where someone must be killed has only happened once before, to the groom's aunt, the only widow there. Consider that, if all games had you kill someone, either the family had died long ago, or they would all be widows.